# How to handle deeplink with branch.io sdk for flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, branch, deep-linking

I am trying to handle deeplink with branch sdk in flutter app.
I have used routemaster library for navigation.
When I open my external deeplink it calls route map's route not found and it considers it as unknown path, bence it redirects to my unknown route page.
And later the branch's listener is triggered.
How can I bypass routemaster's callback in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can move **FlutterBranchSdk.initSession().listen()** this function to the initial route of your app. it will solve your problem.
If this not helps you. then you can ask me for more help, so I need to look at your code for better support. try this if it doesn’t work feel free to contact me.